# DevExpress WinForms NavBar mixed content

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to make main menu for my WindowsForms MDI application and I want to explore using DevExpress NavBar control. There are examples of nesting another NavBar controls into main NavBar groups, but I cannot put mixed content: NavBarItemLink and another NavBar in the same group.

There are great number of examples but I did not find the exact example for this.
I see that using NavBarGroupControlContainer enables adding another NavBars (or any other control) but I cannot add NavBarItemLinks along with that.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this? I think it is a pretty common to have mixed items in a menu.

[image]

As you can see on the picture, there are two main groups: "Letter Sections" and "Contacts". In "Contacts" group there is another NavBar with two more groups: "Sender" and "Recipient". I want to be able to add NavBarItemLink to Contacts group, to be in the same hiearchical level like "Sender" and "Recipient".

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I edited a question with picture and explanation